# Don't apply CSS for specific parents class

Tags: css

I have html like

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Values</label>
      <div class="form-inline">
        @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.Min).Decimals(2);
        @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.Max).Decimals(2);
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Kendo's numeric text box has `.k-numerictextbox` class. and i have CSS

```
.form-group .k-numerictextbox {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

with this settings currently CSS is getting applied to NumericTextBox.

I dont want CSS to apply on NumericTextBox if its under `form-inline` class

Answer (score 1):

For this **specific** html structure (*there is always one element between `.k-numerictextbox` and `.form-group` which either is or not `.form-inline`*) then

```css
.form-group *:not(.form-inline) .k-numerictextbox {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Values</label>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <input class="k-numerictextbox" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Values</label>
      <div class="form-not-inline">
        <input class="k-numerictextbox" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

(*keep in mind that it is a fragile rule, because if there is yet another container of the `.k-numerictextbox` inside the `.form-group` it will not work*)

Answer (score 0):

I would remove using `!important` since it's probably not needed. Add another rule with more specificity (including the `.form-inline` would be a good way to do this:

```
.form-group .k-numerictextbox {
    width: 100%;
}
.form-group .form-inline .k-numerictextbox {
    width: auto;
}
```